# how to redirect from one controller to onother controller for authorization in mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, redirect, roles

I am trying a implement a Custom Forms Authentication using Membership and Roles.
It has two controllers, Home and MyAccount. Now I need to redirect from MyAccount controller to the Home controller for check whether is the person Admin or Client (Depend on Roles) and for corresponding View.But I cant able to redirect to Home Controller for Authorization.

> MyAccount Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Login l, string returnUrl = "")
    { if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var isValidUser = Membership.ValidateUser(l.UserName, l.Password);
            if (isValidUser)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(l.UserName, l.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else              
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("????", "Home");
                }
            }
        }
        ViewBag.ErrorMassage = "Wrong Id or Password";
        ModelState.Remove("Password");
        return View();
```

}

> And Home Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize (Roles= "Admin")]
    public ActionResult AdminIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize (Roles = "Client")]
    public ActionResult Client()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Is this possible to redirect from MyAccount to Home controller to check roles?

Comment: What you want to do after checking the roles ? redirect to different action methods ? I would say you do that in your Login action method (or a service /helper call) from that method. After getting the result (to determine which role he belongs to), you can do a redirect to appropriate action method.

Comment: Thanks... I got it :) @Shyju